How to extract text content preserving its formatting using DOM
I am developing a Chrome extension that can extract job descriptions from LinkedIn job posts. However, when I use .textContent or .innerText in DOM manipulation to extract the job description, the output does not match the formatting or appearance of manually copying and pasting the job description into a document. How can I resolve this issue?

can you just use .innerHTML to preserve the tags?

I want to preserve the formatting.

As @dandavis says, I think you can do element.innerHTML to preserve formatting if what you mean by formatting is: list, font weight, font size, etc.
For example, for this page: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/collections/hiring-in-network/?currentJobId=4093133656
I can do document.querySelector('article').innerHTML to obtain the job description with it's format as shown here:


<div class="jobs-description__content jobs-description-content
">
    <div class="jobs-box__html-content
  gCeSRvuwijzmTJHsHVmaREDPgtRKEJIw
  t-14 t-normal
  jobs-description-content__text--stretch" id="job-details" tabindex="-1">
        <h2 class="text-heading-large">
            About the job
        </h2>

        <!----> <div class="mt4">
            <p dir="ltr">
                <span><p><!---->Hi! We are GeekGarden, a consultant IT
                        company.<!----></p></span><span><p><!---->We're hiring
                        the best candidate for
                        position:<!----></p></span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->Backend
                        Developer Golang<!----><span><strong><span
                                    class="white-space-pre">
                                </span>OR<!----></strong></span><span
                            class="white-space-pre">
                        </span>Ruby<!----></p></span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->This
                        position is for our client : SaaS
                        company<!----></p></span><span><p><!---->Onsite
                        Yogyakarta<!----></p></span><span><p><!---->For 6 months
                        contract
                        base<!----></p></span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->Job
                        Descriptions<!----></p></span><span>
                    <ul><span><li><!---->Design, develop, and maintain backend
                                services and APIs using Golang or using Ruby on
                                Rails<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Write
                                clean, maintainable, and efficient
                                code<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Implement
                                scalable server-side logic and optimize
                                applications for
                                performance<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Collaborate
                                with the product team to understand requirements
                                and translate them into technical
                                specifications<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Integrate
                                third-party APIs and services as
                                needed<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Identify,
                                troubleshoot, and resolve performance
                                bottlenecks and
                                bugs<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Conduct
                                code reviews and provide constructive feedback
                                to other team
                                members<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Ensure
                                data security, system scalability, and high
                                availability<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Participate
                                in the full software development lifecycle,
                                including testing and
                                deployment<!----></li></span></ul>
                </span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->Job
                        Requirements<!----></p></span><span>
                    <ul><span><li><!---->Bachelor's degree in Computer Science,
                                Engineering, or a related field (or equivalent
                                experience)<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->3+
                                years of proven experience as a Backend
                                Developer<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Strong
                                expertise in Golang or Ruby on Rails programming
                                languages<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Experience
                                with RESTful APIs, microservices architecture,
                                and web service
                                frameworks<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Familiarity
                                with SQL and NoSQL databases (e.g., PostgreSQL,
                                MySQL, MongoDB,
                                Redis)<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Understanding
                                of version control systems (e.g.,
                                Git)<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Strong
                                problem-solving skills and the ability to write
                                efficient, scalable
                                code<!----></li></span><span><li><span><strong><!---->Willing
                                        to work with project-based
                                        contract<!----></strong></span></li></span><span><li><span><strong><!---->Willing
                                        to join
                                        immediately<!----></strong></span></li></span><span><li><span><strong><!---->Willing
                                        to work onsite in
                                        Yogyakarta<!----></strong></span></li></span></ul>
                </span>
            </p>
            <!----> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jobs-description__details">
        <!----> </div>
</div>

<div class="jobs-description__content jobs-description-content
">
    <div class="jobs-box__html-content
  gCeSRvuwijzmTJHsHVmaREDPgtRKEJIw
  t-14 t-normal
  jobs-description-content__text--stretch" id="job-details" tabindex="-1">
        <h2 class="text-heading-large">
            About the job
        </h2>

        <!----> <div class="mt4">
            <p dir="ltr">
                <span><p><!---->Hi! We are GeekGarden, a consultant IT
                        company.<!----></p></span><span><p><!---->We're hiring
                        the best candidate for
                        position:<!----></p></span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->Backend
                        Developer Golang<!----><span><strong><span
                                    class="white-space-pre">
                                </span>OR<!----></strong></span><span
                            class="white-space-pre">
                        </span>Ruby<!----></p></span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->This
                        position is for our client : SaaS
                        company<!----></p></span><span><p><!---->Onsite
                        Yogyakarta<!----></p></span><span><p><!---->For 6 months
                        contract
                        base<!----></p></span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->Job
                        Descriptions<!----></p></span><span>
                    <ul><span><li><!---->Design, develop, and maintain backend
                                services and APIs using Golang or using Ruby on
                                Rails<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Write
                                clean, maintainable, and efficient
                                code<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Implement
                                scalable server-side logic and optimize
                                applications for
                                performance<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Collaborate
                                with the product team to understand requirements
                                and translate them into technical
                                specifications<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Integrate
                                third-party APIs and services as
                                needed<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Identify,
                                troubleshoot, and resolve performance
                                bottlenecks and
                                bugs<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Conduct
                                code reviews and provide constructive feedback
                                to other team
                                members<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Ensure
                                data security, system scalability, and high
                                availability<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Participate
                                in the full software development lifecycle,
                                including testing and
                                deployment<!----></li></span></ul>
                </span><span><p><span><br></span></p></span><span><p><!---->Job
                        Requirements<!----></p></span><span>
                    <ul><span><li><!---->Bachelor's degree in Computer Science,
                                Engineering, or a related field (or equivalent
                                experience)<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->3+
                                years of proven experience as a Backend
                                Developer<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Strong
                                expertise in Golang or Ruby on Rails programming
                                languages<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Experience
                                with RESTful APIs, microservices architecture,
                                and web service
                                frameworks<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Familiarity
                                with SQL and NoSQL databases (e.g., PostgreSQL,
                                MySQL, MongoDB,
                                Redis)<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Understanding
                                of version control systems (e.g.,
                                Git)<!----></li></span><span><li><!---->Strong
                                problem-solving skills and the ability to write
                                efficient, scalable
                                code<!----></li></span><span><li><span><strong><!---->Willing
                                        to work with project-based
                                        contract<!----></strong></span></li></span><span><li><span><strong><!---->Willing
                                        to join
                                        immediately<!----></strong></span></li></span><span><li><span><strong><!---->Willing
                                        to work onsite in
                                        Yogyakarta<!----></strong></span></li></span></ul>
                </span>
            </p>
            <!----> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jobs-description__details">
        <!----> </div>
</div>



If this is not what you're looking for, then please specify what you mean by format

Thank you for your answer. The problem is saving this on a db and display them in a text editor by fetching from db

You can use HTML parser to "convert" the string from yourdb into HTML element

@RasangaLakshith do you solve this already? I think parsing the string into HTML elements and rendering it on WYSIWYG text editor should work quite fine. If you're still having a struggle, can you tell me what editor you're using?
